# Second spinner not loading based on previous spinner from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am populating two spinner from sqlite. Now what I want that when my Activity is created then all state populate in `spnState`. But when I select any state from spinner then I want to bind District from sqlite in `spnDistrict`. I am getting problem when I select state after that list of district not showing in district spinner it is only showing "select district". How can I achieve that.

```
public void SpinnerValue(){
    /*-----------------------Fill State start here----------------------------*/

            try {
                ArrayList<String> state_array = new ArrayList<String>();
                state_array.add("Select State");
                Cursor cursor_State = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo as _id,cCodeName FROM CodeMaster where nCtgId = 6", null);


                if (cursor_State.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //assing values
                        String stateID = cursor_State.getString(0);
                        String stateName = cursor_State.getString(1);
                        stateData = stateName;
                        state_array.add(stateData);


                    } while (cursor_State.moveToNext());
                }
                ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, state_array);
                spnState.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
                cursor_State.close();
                spnState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        state = spnState.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo FROM CodeMaster where cCodeName = '" + state + "'", null);

                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                //assing values
                                stateCodeId = cursor.getString(0);

                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                });
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            /*-----------------------Fill District start here----------------------------*/

            try {
                ArrayList<String> district_array = new ArrayList<String>();
                district_array.add("Select District");
                Cursor cursor_District = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo as _id,cCodeName FROM CodeMaster where nParentSerialNo = '"+stateCodeId+"'", null);


                if (cursor_District.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //assing values
                        String districtID = cursor_District.getString(0);
                        String districtName = cursor_District.getString(1);
                        districtData = districtName;
                        district_array.add(districtData);


                    } while (cursor_District.moveToNext());
                }
                ArrayAdapter district_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, district_array);
                spnDistrict.setAdapter(district_Adapter);
                cursor_District.close();
                spnDistrict.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        district = spnDistrict.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo FROM CodeMaster where cCodeName = '" + district + "'", null);

                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                //assing values
                                districtCodeId = cursor.getString(0);

                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        cursor.close();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                });
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
}
```

Comment: Where you have put all this code ? In one simple method or how you have managed ? Put entire code for this

Comment: I put this code in function and I call that function in onCreate.

Comment: Entire code or for district do you have separate ?

Comment: Put your log here.

Comment: Check my answer, it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and you are setting all values in one simple method, therefore it will not take stateId to fetch districts, So just apply below two method and call first in onCreate method to resolve your issue,

**Call Below method in onCreate() method**

```
  // In onCreate() method call below method
  fillStateData();

  public void fillStateData()
  {
     try {
           ArrayList<String> state_array = new ArrayList<String>();
           state_array.add("Select State");
           Cursor cursor_State = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo as _id,cCodeName FROM CodeMaster where nCtgId = 6", null);


           if (cursor_State.moveToFirst()) 
           {
               do {
                    //assing values
                    String stateID = cursor_State.getString(0);
                    String stateName = cursor_State.getString(1);
                    stateData = stateName;
                    state_array.add(stateData);
                } while (cursor_State.moveToNext());
            }
            ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, state_array);
            spnState.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
            cursor_State.close();
            spnState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    state = spnState.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo FROM CodeMaster where cCodeName = '" + state + "'", null);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {                        
                            stateCodeId = cursor.getString(0);
                    }
                    cursor.close();

                   fillDistrictData(stateCodeId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
   }






public void fillDistrictData(String stateCodeId)
{
        try {
                ArrayList<String> district_array = new ArrayList<String>();
                district_array.add("Select District");
                Cursor cursor_District = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo as _id,cCodeName FROM CodeMaster where nParentSerialNo = '"+stateCodeId+"'", null);


                if (cursor_District.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //assing values
                        String districtID = cursor_District.getString(0);
                        String districtName = cursor_District.getString(1);
                        districtData = districtName;
                        district_array.add(districtData);


                    } while (cursor_District.moveToNext());
                }
                ArrayAdapter district_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, district_array);
                spnDistrict.setAdapter(district_Adapter);
                cursor_District.close();
                spnDistrict.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        district = spnDistrict.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo FROM CodeMaster where cCodeName = '" + district + "'", null);

                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                //assing values
                                districtCodeId = cursor.getString(0);

                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        cursor.close();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }


                });
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

   }
```